# Set default music app

Tags: macos, itunes

Can I change the default music app on OS X? When I accidentally press the play/pause button on my headset it opens the Music app (formerly part of iTunes), which I never use or plan to use ever.

I will be super happy to map that button to mute/unmute the system audio, but that could be a long shot.

I would be satisfied by setting my default app to VLC, so at least I can use the button to play and pause the music on my favorite app.

As a last option, I'd settle for disabling that functionality, so at least accidental presses don't fire up a nagging app on top of my work forcing me to close it.

Comment: Which version of macOS, what kind of headset do you use?

Comment: OS X Catalina (10.15.7) and a cheap generic headset with mic, it has a hub in the middle of the cable with a volume rocker and a single button, apparently to play/pause music and take/end calls.

Answer (score 1):

How to change default music app on macOS:

Right-click on your audio file (mine is mp3), and select 'Get Info'

[image: Right clicking]

Dropdown 'Open With'

[image: Dropdown]

Select your desired app, from the app chooser (I chose VLC)

[image: Choosing VLC]

Then, click on 'Change All'. What it will do is when you open the mp3 file, it will open in VLC. So you will have to do the steps again with an m4a or wav or ogg files.

[image: Change All]

Now if you open the app, it will run in VLC!

[image: Opened in VLC]

[YouTube video to change default music/audio app](https://youtu.be/ZuMx8FYSqxQ)

Answer (score 0):

There's an app called [NoTunes](https://github.com/tombonez/noTunes). It's a background service that will stop the Music app from launching and allows you to set up an alternative app if needed.

Since it's a background service, it would consume some energy.

It's not perfect, but it works.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. Please try to summarise the content of your link so it can be followed without the need to follow the link. In this way answers can remain visible even if the link goes dead. Links without any follow up are not a particularly good practice.